# Form select field options array in Rails. The rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, html-select

This is a simple question yet I'm having a hard time finding an answer. I have a select field in my form and I want to build the options array depending on my query records count.

I'm getting my count like so in my controller:

```
@num_pages= Page.where(:site_id => @siteid).count
```

I want my options array to just be like {["1", 1], ["2", 2], ...} all the way up to @num_pages.

Now **I KNOW** I can just do a loop and build that array but I want to know if there is a more **"rails"** way to do it. So that my select code could still be as simple as this:

```
<%= select_tag(:nav_order, options_for_select(@num_pages)) %>
```

...without using loops and array pushes and what have you.

UPDATE

Thanks to the responses my code now works like this. I decided to keep the mapping in the view instead of the controller however.

```
<% options_array = (1..@page_count).to_a.collect{|p| ["#{p}", p]} %>  
<%= select_tag(:nav_order, options_for_select(options_array)) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the array in the controller?

```
num = Page.where(:site_id => @siteid).count
@num_pages = (1..num).to_a.collect{|p| ["#{p}", p]}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your question, I think this should do the trick:

```
Array.new(@num_pages){ |i| [(i+1).to_s, i+1] }
```

Example with a number and the output:

```
irb(main):001:0> Array.new(5){ |i| [(i+1).to_s, i+1] }
=> [["1", 1], ["2", 2], ["3", 3], ["4", 4], ["5", 5]]
```

Not sure if this would be the "rails" way, but I think it's simple enough :)